# Explode a dataframe column of csv text into columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|serial_number|          test_date|             s3_path|    table_csv_data    |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     1050D1BE|2019-05-08 09:26:55|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-25 06:54:28|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:07:21|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:07:21|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-25 00:19:52|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-24 22:24:40|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-09-12 22:15:19|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:27:56|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

sample table_csv_data column contains:

```
timestamp,partition,offset,key,value
1625218801350,97,33009,2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP,458969040
1625218801349,41,33018,3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP,17569160
```

Trying to achieve the final dataframe as below, please help

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
|serial_number|          test_date|           timestamp|    partition    |  offset   |    key                            |    value     |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11| 1625218801350      |    97           |  33009    | 2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP |  458969040   |
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11| 1625218801349      |    41           |  33018    | 3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP |  17569160    |               
    ..
    ..
    ..
```

I cannot think of an approach, kindly help with some suggestions.

As I alternative, I converted the sting csv data into list using csv_reader as well as below, but post that I have been blocked

```
[[timestamp,partition,offset,key,value],
[1625218801350, 97, 33009, 2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP, 458969040]
[1625218801349, 41,33018, 3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP, 17569160]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("table_csv_data", F.split("table_csv_data", ",")).select(
    "serial_number",
    "test_date",
    F.col("table_csv_data").getItem(0).alias("timestamp"),
    F.col("table_csv_data").getItem(1).alias("partition"),
    ... # Do the same for all the columns you need
)
```